# Realizar consulta MAX() dentro de un SUM() en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta la cual me muestra la sumatoria de dinero por medio de un `SUM()` y muestra el `VALOR` del dinero agrupado por `PLACA` de esta forma:

```
SELECT PLACA, SUM(VALOR) AS SUMA 
FROM `huawei_combustible` 
WHERE YEAR(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 2018 AND MONTH(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 01 
GROUP BY PLACA  
ORDER BY `SUMA` DESC
```

Pero lo que necesito es poder mostrar el valor máximo de esa primer consulta. algo como esta:

```
SELECT PLACA, SUM(VALOR) AS SUMA
(SELECT MAX(SUMA) FROM `huawei_combustible`) 
FROM `huawei_combustible`
WHERE YEAR(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 2018 AND MONTH(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 01
```

Comment: Primero deberías aclarar qué manejador de base de datos usas. Pero ¿Exactamente cuál es el problema? ¿La consulta no te devuelve lo que deseas? ¿Te devuelve un error? ¿Solo deseas mostrar un registro? Es posible que solo desees un TOP si es SQL Server, o un LIMIT si es MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la respuesta que puedo brindarte sé que funcionaría con una Base de Datos **Postgres** o **MySql**. Espero que te sea útil:

**Solución:**

```
SELECT PLACA, SUM(VALOR) AS SUMA 
FROM `huawei_combustible` 
WHERE YEAR(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 2018 AND MONTH(FECHA_TANQUEO) = 01 
GROUP BY PLACA  
ORDER BY `SUMA` DESC
LIMIT 1
```